# array becomes null because I can't send product id with get_file_content

Tags: php, woocommerce, foreach

I cannot see the details of the product I have selected in my product list with the woocommerce rest api
The main problem is that when I write the id of the product, I see it as json, but I have a problem when I want to include it in an array.
The main problem is that I can't send product id to single_product_connect.php with get_file_content, so it shows $ data array empty

form code;

```
<form action="single_product.php" name="update" method="get">
<td><input type="submit" name="edit"id="edit" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/></td></form>
```

single_product.php code;

```
<?php  
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api-woocommerce/single_product_connect.php');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
?>
<?php foreach ( $data as $row ) : ?>
<?= $row['id']; ?>
<?= $row['name']; ?>    //I wrote a small piece for testing
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

single_product_connect.php code;

```
<?php $product_id = $_GET['edit'];?>
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->get("products/{$product_id}",$data)); ?>
```

error screen;
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woocommerce\single_product.php on line 19////The code in line 19:

```
<?php foreach ( $data as $row ) : ?>
```

Comment: After decoding the json, check what is the output of this `json_last_error()`

Comment: Which line exactly do I add this code to?

Comment: I've modified the answer, check

Answer (score 1):

When you use file_get_contents to get single_product_connect.php with http you can pass "edit" as a parameter if you concatenate query parameters to your url.

Try this change:

```
$id = /*some id*/;
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api-woocommerce/single_product_connect.php?edit='.$id);
```

Comment: $id = /*some id*/;
what variable should I set here?

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned `can't send product id to single_product_connect.php with get_file_content` so, when you're calling the remote url, the return value is an empty string which on `json_decode()` becomes `null`. You can check this by just adding this `json_last_error()` after `json_decode()` like this

```php
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$erorr = json_last_error();

var_dump($data);
echo $error;
```

You can first append the product_id to the url and then can make the call to the url using `file_get_contents` like this

```php
$url = "http://localhost/api-woocommerce/single_product_connect.php?product_id=<product_id>";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

but I would suggest you to either use `curl` (*recommended*) or `fsockopen`.

With curl, it's very easy

```php
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
$url = "http://localhost/api-woocommerce/single_product_connect.php?product_id=<product_id>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($output, true);

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
    exit();
}

foreach ($data as $row) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I wrote the codes you shared. output result = https://imgur.com/CMW48Mh   Will I make any changes regarding single_product_connect.php?

Comment: @hulk6hulk I've just shared the sample, you'll need to make changes in the code as per your requirement like what is parameter from which you're fetching the product id in `single_product_connect.php` file and it's value. You'll have to add your logic in the `foreach` loop after getting the response from `single_product_connect.php` url etc etc

Comment: https://prnt.sc/13b6qix I will type the same as in the woocommerce curl code to single_product_contact.php I am getting a Syntax error right now.