# Retrieve api data with curl

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce

I am writing woocommerce rest api. When I connect to single_product_connect.php with curl, I get "snytax error" error. how can i solve the problem.My aim is to write this code. Select any of the products in my Woocommerce product list and view the details of that product.
form code;

```
<form action="single_product.php" name="update" method="get">
<td><input type="submit" name="edit"id="edit" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"/></td> 
</form>
```

single_product.php;

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();


$url = "http://localhost/api-woocommerce/single_product_connect.php?<queryParam>=<product_id>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


$output = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($output, true);

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
echo json_last_error_msg();
exit();
}

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $row['name'];
}
?>
```

single_product_connect.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
'https://blog.test.com',
'ck_bb7cb132da9dfac541570',
'cs_327a1926654e4e20610',
[
    'wp_api' => true,
    'version' => 'wc/v3',
    'query_string_auth' => true // Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under 
HTTPS
]
);
?>
<?php $product_id = $_GET['edit'];?>
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->get("products/{$product_id}",$data)); ?>
```

error screen;

```
Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting most likely relates to the **single_product_connect.php** file:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'HTTPS' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in your code on line 14
```

All you need is:

- Add a comma after `'query_string_auth' => true` *(so it will be `'query_string_auth' => true,`)*
- Remove the `HTTPS` text if it is not to be there *(keep in mind that written in this way it is considered as a constant, if you want to use it as a string you will have to use quotes)*

To go beyond your question, I recommend that you also read these answers:

- [Why would one omit the close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag)
- [PHP Manual > Language Reference > Basic syntax > PHP tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: I'll try it. If you remember I had a problem with woocommerce. It still goes on and I wanted to experiment with curl this time. My main problem is that the array fails when I send the id with get.

Comment: I tried but the same problem persists.:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660295/array-becomes-null-because-i-cant-send-product-id-with-get-file-content   You solved my previous problem and now I will be very grateful if you can. I have been dealing with this error for days.